# What to do with answers that are well tried, but wrong?

Tags: discussion, answers, voting

Sometimes, when a question is a bit vague, answers like this can happen:

> This seems to be a problem with ****
>
> Try to do ****

The reasoning is right, nothing in the question may even indicate that it could be wrong, but the problem happens, in this case, to be something else.

What should we do with these answers? Is it better to keep them, as they give ideas to other people finding this question? Or should the author remove it, since it doesn't give a solution to the OP?

I would personally like to keep these answers without voting them up or down, for the above reason, but what do you think about that?

Comment: Moderators don't delete wrong answers, so it isn't a mater of keeping vs not keeping.  The OP can choose to delete him/herself, or the community (actually 10K users) can do it if it gets downvoted enough.  So for the average user, downvoting and/or commenting are the only tools.

Comment: @psubsee2003 That's true. But I've been able to get authors to remove answers that were shot from the hip by putting a comment telling exactly how the answer does not apply to the problem at hand.

Comment: That was my question, what the author of such an answer should do and what vote (up, down or nothing) is better. But I'm ok with "let the community decide".

Comment: I have problems with this too.  I see an issue, but it may, or may not, have a bearing on the OP bug, or it may just be a debugging suggestion.  Squashing my theory/suggestion into a comment is awkward, but if I post an answer that proves to be irrelevant, I could get downvotes:(

Answer (score 4):

I'd comment on the answer explaining why it's not applicable in this case, and in which cases it would be applicable, so that future viewers will know.

Comment: this, + downvote. if it's wrong, it's still wrong regardless of how much effort was put into it. Part of submitting an answer is accepting the risk that said answer might be downvoted. If you post an answer without knowing all the facts of the question, that's the risk you're taking.

Comment: It's not really a question of how much effort was put into it, but the fact that the answer can be useful to a lot of people googling the same sort of problem.